# Cannot invoke a method, even if it's public

Tags: java, reflection

here's my code.
And it throws

> can not access a member of class sun.management.ClassLoadingImpl with
>   modifiers "public"

I first reflect the method, then call it. And as you see, getObjectName is a public method, but why cannot I invoke it?

I think the original code is confused, I paste an explicit one here:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Object bean = ManagementFactory.getClassLoadingMXBean();
        Method[] methods = bean.getClass().getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().equals("getObjectName")) {
                System.out.println(method.getName() + ":" + method.invoke(bean).toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is old...

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Method[] methods = ManagementFactory.class.getMethods();
        System.out.println(ManagementFactory.getClassLoadingMXBean().getObjectName());
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().startsWith("get") && method.getName().endsWith("Bean")) {
                System.out.println(method.getName());
                Object bean = method.invoke(null);
                printBean(bean);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printBean(Object bean) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Method[] methods = bean.getClass().getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                System.out.println(method.getName());
                System.out.println(method.getName() + ":" + method.invoke(bean).toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add implementation of `getObjectName()`

Comment: You should not call `sun.*` classes directly

Comment: The error occurs in which line?

Comment: method.invoke(bean) throws the exception

Comment: I think it is because `ClassLoadingImpl` is a package private class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass the bean instance to invoke the method since the class is not `public`. You should check the visibility of the class first:

```
if (!Modifier.isPublic(bean.getClass().getModifiers())) {
    System.out.println(bean + " is not public");
    return;
}
```

Another possibility is to set the method to be accessible:

```
method.setAccessible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `getMethod[s]` on a specific `Class` instance, like `bean.getClass()` you may get `Method` instances whose `getDeclaringClass()` is not `public`, so invoking them is not allowed, even if these methods are actually overriding/implementing a `public` method of a `public` class or interface.

This is the case for `getObjectName`, which can be invoked when acquiring the `Method` from the declaring interface.

```
Object bean = ManagementFactory.getClassLoadingMXBean();
Method method = ClassLoadingMXBean.class.getMethod("getObjectName");
System.out.println(method.getName()+": "+method.invoke(bean).toString());
```

but, of course, this has no advantage over

```
ClassLoadingMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getClassLoadingMXBean();
System.out.println("getObjectName: "+bean.getObjectName());
```

If you want to collect properties dynamically, you should use the `MBeanInfo`, which is intended for exactly that purpose:

```
ClassLoadingMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getClassLoadingMXBean();
final MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

MBeanAttributeInfo[] attr = mBeanServer.getMBeanInfo(bean.getObjectName()).getAttributes();
String[] attrNames = new String[attr.length];
for(int ix=0; ix<attr.length; ix++) attrNames[ix] = attr[ix].getName();

for(Attribute a: mBeanServer.getAttributes(bean.getObjectName(), attrNames).asList())
    System.out.println(a.getName()+": "+a.getValue());
```

You don’t even need the `bean` instance for this query, as you can replace `bean.getObjectName()` with the result of `ObjectName.getInstance(ManagementFactory.CLASS_LOADING_MXBEAN_NAME)`.